# How to add snap to Dell's snap store

Tags: ubuntu, gateway

How do you add your own custom snap to the Dell snap store? Documentation only shows how to add snaps from the store to the device inventory.

[Dell Edge Device Manager Administrator's Guide](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/se/sv/sebsdt1/wyse-cloud-client-manager/edm_r15_admin_pub/managing-edge-gateway---snappy-inventory?guid=guid-891f6d5d-7ff5-4610-a497-4df6004e04d9&lang=en-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one creates a brand store, one can choose to make it public or private. I don't believe Dell's is public, so they'd probably have to give you access.